# Addition of SUM of 4 independent tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 4 tables, which has two fields in common

total_share and idea_user_id

i have a queru written to calculate total_income out of the SUM of total_share fro each table

here's my query

```
SELECT(
                         (SELECT SUM(total_share) FROM `idea_submitter_percentage` WHERE idea_user_id='3')
                           +
                         (SELECT SUM(total_share) FROM `idea_revisor_percentage` WHERE idea_user_id='3')
                           +
                         (SELECT SUM(total_share) FROM `idea_contributor_percentage` WHERE idea_user_id='3')
                            +
                         (SELECT SUM(total_share) FROM `idea_comparisor_percentage` WHERE idea_user_id='3')
                )
AS total_income
```

the problem is that it works fine when i have atleast one row in each table where idea_user_id='3'

but if i have one table where no entries are present based on idea_user_id='3', then it returns me NULL, as such the total amount named total_income returns me NULL

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

You could use `coalesce()` to deal with the nulls:

```
select coalesce(sum(...), 0) ...
```

Or you could move the sum in the outer query, and stick to union all in the subqueries:

```
select sum(...)
from ( select ... from ...
       union all
       select ... from ...
       ... ) as sub
...
```

You could also join all the tables (juergen's answer).

Answer (score 0):

This type of syntax works in oracle...  basically, you need an outer join.

```
    SELECT NVL(SUM(total_share),0) 
FROM `idea_comparisor_percentage` 
WHERE idea_user_id (+) ='3'
```